# Number of ways to place exactly two kings in each column such that no king attacks another

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

A regular  King  in a chess board can attack all its adjacent 8 cells (vertical, horizontal or diagonal). Now you are given a $10 \times n$  chessboard, your task is to place exactly two kings in each column such  that no king attacks another. What is the number of ways to do that?

#### Progress

I can count that in  column A we can place two non attacking kings in $36$ ways.

Comment: What work have you done on it so far?

Comment: i can count that in A collumn we can place two non attacking kings in 36 ways

Comment: Okay, you should add any work you've done to your question.

Comment: what work , i've added ! in my last comment

Comment: Please edit your question with the work you've indicated in your comment. It should be part of the question, not hidden in a comment to the question.

Comment: What if n is really small like 1 or 2? Are there still that many possibilities if $n$ is really small?

Comment: n can be bigger

Answer (score 5):

It's the number of walks of length $n$ in the graph:

[image]

We draw an edge between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ if a column with kings in rows $a$ and $b$ can be placed next to a column with kings in rows $c$ and $d$.

So, the number could be computed by taking powers of its adjacency matrix and summing the entries.